# HDFS Flume sink - Roll by File

Tags: flume

Is it possible for HDFS Flume sink to roll whenever a single file (from a Flume source, say Spooling Directory) ends, instead of rolling after certain bytes (hdfs.rollSize), time (hdfs.rollInterval), or events (hdfs.rollCount)?

Can Flume be configured so that a single file is a single event?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Reagarding your first question, it is not possible due to the sinks logic is *disconnected* from the sources logic. I mean, a sink only sees events being put into the channel which must be processed by him; the sink does not know if an event is the first or the last regarding a file.

Of course, you could try to create your own source (or extend an existing one) in order to add a header to the event with a value meaning "this is the last event". Then, another custom sink could behave depending on such a header: for instance, if the header is not set, then the events are not persisted but stored in memory until the header is seen; then all the information is persisted in the final backend as a bach. Other possibility is that custom sink persists the data in a file until the header is seen; then the file is closed and another one is opened.

Regarding your second question, it depends on the sink. The [`spooldir`](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) source behaves based on the `deserializer` parameter; by default its value is `LINE`, what means:

> Specify the deserializer used to parse the file into events. Defaults to parsing each line as an event. The class specified must implement EventDeserializer.Builder.

But other custom Java classes can be configured, as said above; for instance, a deserialized for the whole file.

Comment: Regarding the header solution, I'm now thinking despite the channels behave as a FIFO queue by default, this behaviour may be changed by the sinks when an event cannot be persisted (e.g. temporal loss of connection with the backend). In that case, the event is, let's say, reinjected at the begining of the queue for a alter retry and then any order is totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can set rollsize to a small number combined with BlobDeserializer to load file by file instead of combining into blocks. This is really helpful when you have unsplittable binary files such as PDF or gz files.

This is part of the configuration that is relevant:

```
#Set deserializer to BlobDeserializer and set the maximum blob size to be 1GB.
#Notice that the blobs have to fit in memory so this doesn't work for files that cannot fit in memory.
agent.sources.spool.deserializer = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder
agent.sources.spool.deserializer.maxBlobLength = 1000000000

#Set rollSize to 1024 to avoid combining multiple small files into one part.
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollSize = 1024
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question "Can Flume be configured so that a single file is a single event?" is yes.

Yo only have to configure the following property to be 1:

```
hdfs.rollCount = 1
```

I'm looking for a solution for your first question, because sometimes the file is too big and it's needed to split the file in several chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any event headers in `hdfs.path`. ( https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink )

If you are using Spooling Directory Source, you can enable putting the file name in the events using `fileHeaderKey` or `basenameHeaderKey` ( https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source ).

> Can Flume be configured so that a single file is a single event?

It *could be*, however it is **not recommended**. The underlying implementation (protobuf) limits file sizes to 64m. Flume events are to be small in size due to its architecture and design. (Fault-tolerance, etc.)